# Can't javax.servlet in google i/o code 2013

Tags: java, servlets, android-studio

I have downloaded. using git, the Google I/O app from there website and I can't get it to compile. Android Studio is giving me the error: "the package javax.servlet does not exists" from the following code

```
package com.google.android.apps.iosched.gcm.server.cron;

import com.google.android.apps.iosched.gcm.server.BaseServlet;
import com.google.android.apps.iosched.gcm.server.db.DeviceStore;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;`

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

How will I be able to install the package?

Comment: Are you using Maven? Gradle? Neither?

Comment: If you are running an ant script please add the necessary java ee libraries. It seems the project requires it

Comment: I believe it is using Gradle